# oAuth in Flutter

Tags: oauth, dart, flutter, package

Anyone Know How Can I Make oAuth Login (No Firebase) By Flutter Because Firebase In Future Need Money

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/oauth2

Comment: Is it not there in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/oauth2 ?

Comment: there is one example for dart i need another one for flutter